# UIPIckerView - TimePicker with available slots

Tags: swift

I want to create `UIPickerView`, where users can select hour and minute. This picker has two components - hours and minutes.

But the user may have busy slots. For example, it's a 14:15 with a duration of 45 minutes.
So, I want to delete this range from picker - from 14:15 by 15:00. How to create it?

UPD: I want to create an array for `UIPicker`. This array will be used in the UIPickerView to display free time so that the employee can set the start time for a new task. The task is always completed in 45 minutes.

This `UIPickerView` should only show free time.

I have data: 1.start of working hours 2.end of working hours 3. At what time were other tasks started

Accordingly, when creating a task, we cannot overlap with the time of other tasks.

And if the time is now 12:00 and the nearest other task starts at 12:10, then the nearest available time for selecting a task should be 12:55. Because the task execution time is always 45 minutes and we cannot overlap.

Answer (score 0):

add UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource to your viewcontroller:

```
class yourVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

 //... your code
}
```

Then add those methods in the "... your code" along with the code you have.

```
let arrHours = [0...24] 
var arrMins = [0...60]


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
   return 2
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
switch component {
    case 1: return arrHours.count
    case 2: return arrMins.count
}
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch component {
        case 1: return "\(arrHours[row]) Hours"
        case 2: return "\(arrMins[row]) Min"
    }
 }
```

if a user wants to remove a specific hour just change the arrHours array

Comment: @TheGreatVY hi did my answer help you?

Comment: Hello! Sorry for long answer from myself. My question is too short. I did update my question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UIPickerView, if you just want time selection it is much easier to use [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker).